# Flask on Openshift, nothing is getting logged

Tags: logging, flask, openshift

I've tried everything I can think of but can't figure this out.  Here is my wsgi.py file as it stands right now.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

virtenv = os.path.join(os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_DIR', '.'), '/virtenv/')
virtualenv = os.path.join(virtenv, 'bin/activate_this.py')
try:
    execfile(virtualenv, dict(__file__=virtualenv))
except IOError:
    pass
#
# IMPORTANT: Put any additional includes below this line.  If placed above this
# line, it's possible required libraries won't be in your searchable path
#

import logging, sys
# logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr, level=logging.DEBUG)

from minimal import app as application
application.config.from_object('minimal.config.Production')

log_file_name = os.path.join(
    os.environ.get('OPENSHIFT_PYTHON_LOG_DIR', '.'),
    'app.log')
handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
application.logger.addHandler(handler)
application.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

I've tried all kinds of permutations of this idea and can't get anywhere.  Setting the stream to sys.stderr doesn't work.  Setting it anywhere in my code doesn't seem to work.  Setting the logging handler to any type of handler at an point in my code doesn't seem to help either.  All that ever gets logged in my python.log file is:

```
[Tue Jul 14 12:54:12 2015] [notice] caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
- - - [14/Jul/2015:12:54:12 -0400] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) (internal dummy connection)"
[Tue Jul 14 12:57:30 2015] [notice] SELinux policy enabled; httpd running as context unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c3,c75
[Tue Jul 14 12:57:31 2015] [notice] Digest: generating secret for digest authentication ...
[Tue Jul 14 12:57:31 2015] [notice] Digest: done
[Tue Jul 14 12:57:31 2015] [notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.8 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

And this is only during deployment.  Nothing, even errors or exceptions gets logged.  When I first started my project more stuff was getting logged but somewhere along the line it all disappeared.  The 'app.log' file that you can see I'm trying to create in wsgi.py is never created.

The config file in 'minimal.config' is simply:

```
class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    ASSETS_DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False


class Development(Config):
    DEBUG = True
    ASSETS_DEBUG = True


class Production(Config):
    PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True


class Testing(Config):
    TESTING = True
```

Any idea where I can turn now to try solving this issue?

Comment: It's been 6 months since I played around with openshift but I never could get logging to work correctly using the wsgi.py method.  I even filed a bug report.  They said it was not high priority.  I use the app.py method to lauch my app and logging works as it should.

Comment: I'm using `wsgi.py` method and logging works but I'm setting it up in my `flaskapp.py` file not in the `wsgi.py`. It shouldn't matter I guess but for me it works. Oh and I'm not setting up any stream or file or anything just `basicConfig` for formating ,`setLevel` for default level and that's it.